# Column datatype exceptions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is there a more eloquent/efficient way to perform the following. Using pd.read function I'm importing many files. For most of these all the datatypes in the dataframe want to be one type ie object, however a limited number will be a different type ie float64 or datetime. Is there a way to import all as object except specified. Currently i'm approaching as follows;

```
df = pd.read_csv('filepath', dtype=object)
```

Then;

```
df['column_with_easting&northing'] = pd.to_numeric(df['column_with_easting&northing'])
df['column_with_dd-mm-yyyy] = pd.to_datetime(df['column_with_column_with_dd-mm-yyyy'])
```

I'd like to know if i can do something like all columns are object except date and numeric. If i use

```
df = df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), dtype={'column_with_dd-mm-yyyy': object, 'column_with_easting&northing': np.float64})
```

Then pandas tries to infer the remaining column types giving me a mix of object and float when i know the data is object.

Comment: You'd be better off just specifying object as the default dtype and then convert the other columns to numeric and datetime as a post processing step to make it less complicated

Comment: @EdChum that's what i've gone with but when there are 60 columns and you need to change 10 it makes for very lengthly code

Comment: Make a list of columns that are dates and another for columns that are float. Loop through the lists and perform the appropriate conversion. That will clean up the code a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a combination of `date_parser` and `converters` (parameters of [read_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)) across ranges of columns. Below example uses a csv where first four columns are dates in *dd-mmm-yyyy* format and last 3 columns are strings. Do note range allows stepping for every other columns: `range(0,4,2)`

```
dateparse = lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x, '%d-%b-%Y')

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv',                 
                 parse_dates=list(range(4)), date_parser=dateparse,
                 converters={i:str for i in range(4,7)})
```